# Loop sub folders and make them dynamic links in php

Tags: php

I need help on this one 
I have managed to loop through my parent folder and echo the sub folder en wants to create on `PHP` file that can help me loop through the sub folders. my code is below:

```
<?php
$path="../downloads/pastpapers/UCU/foundations/";
$dir = new DirectoryIterator($path);
foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {
    if ($fileinfo->isDir() && !$fileinfo->isDot()) {
        $dirName=$fileinfo->getFilename();
        echo "<div id='linkFrame'><a href='$dirName.php'><img src='images/folder.png'><br/>$dirName</img></a>   </div>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: have you tried `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` in PHP

Comment: not yet let me check if i could use it en get back to you thnx

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: nl-x my questions is how to make a single php file that can dyanmically process the looped sub-directories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try the following in test file php :

```
<?php
$path = '../downloads/pastpapers/UCU/foundations';
ListFolder($path);

    function ListFolder($path)
    {
        //using the opendir function
        $dir_handle = @opendir($path) or die("Unable to open $path");

        //Leave only the lastest folder name
        $explode = explode("/", $path);
        $dirname = end($explode);

        //display the target folder.
        echo ("<li>$dirname\n");
        echo "<ul>\n";
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir_handle))) 
        {
            if($file!="." && $file!="..")
            {
                if (is_dir($path."/".$file))
                {
                    //Display a list of sub folders.
                    ListFolder($path."/".$file);
                }
                else
                {
                    //Display a list of files.
                    echo "<li>$file</li>";
                }
            }
        }
        echo "</ul>\n";
        echo "</li>\n";

        //closing the directory
        closedir($dir_handle);
    }
?>
```

for more information pls visit [this page](http://www.dmxzone.com/go/14199/list-server-folders-and-files-as-tree-with-folder-view-asp-php/)

Comment: Thank you Mohammad it has worked well am just now trying to add a collapsible menu on the sub directories so the files can be displayed only onClick